# Return a count with linq-to-sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to return a count of new users since a specific date.

Users table has: UserID, username, dateJoined.

```
SELECT COUNT(USERID)
FROM Users
where dateJoined > @date
```

How would this look in linq-to-sql?

Can you use the keyword COUNT?

Answer (score 18):

You can go two routes:

```
var count = (from u in context.Users where u.datJoined > date select u).Count();
```

or

```
var count = context.Users.Where( x => x.datJoined > date).Count();
```

Both are equivalent, it really boils down to a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I think the first one doesn't compile because it requires a select, but I'd recommend the second one.

Comment: You can do the second example with a single call to Count(). int count = context.Users.Count(x => x.datJoined > date);

Comment: The first one works fine as it is now, and it doesn't look like it's been edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
(from u in context.Users where u.dateJoined > date select u).Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a IEnumberable list called users and some variable called somedate.

```
int count = users
   .Where<User>(i => i.dateJoined > someDate)
   .Count<User>();
```

This will work against any IEnumberable list not just Linq to Sql

Comment: It should be noted, though, that this is just calling an extension method. It isn't actually LINQ (in the sense that LINQ is a language syntax for querying; you're just using the extension methods that LINQ uses). Nothing wrong with that, just worth noting.

Comment: You don't need the "Where()". Just put the lambda expression in "Count()".